# How to inspect and clean a small engine stored for year without oil cap?

Tags: small-engine, dust

I recently discovered my wood chipper's oil filler cap is missing.  Assuming it fell off last time I used it, the engine has been uncapped for over a year.

Wind often blows dust and leaves into my garage, where the chipper is stored.

What should I do to inspect and clean the engine before using it again?

Engine details:

- Briggs & Stratton
- Family sbs206u1g1ra:em
- Model 13h
- 206cc
- 5hp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you can do is change the oil. I think your engine is most likely a splash oiling system which does not have a real oil pump or filter (I couldn't find the model you have listed to make sure). While changing the oil, check to see how much schmutz is in there. If there's a bunch, you may want to try and use a flush before using the engine. Continue to flush until it comes clean. Once clean, fill back up with regular oil and let 'er rip. Realistically, there's nothing you'll be able to do to fix anything other than clean the crankcase and change the oil. If there was any damage done, it's done. There's no sense in worrying about it beyond that. More than likely, even if some gunk got into the oil, minimal damage might have been done. This is mainly because with a splash oiling system. it isn't going to push anything through to the bearings (or journal areas) like a pressurized system would.